# Where can I find rhythm and melody for modern spoken Greek?

Tags: resource-request, greek

I am interested in working on rhythm and melody for modern Greek: tempo, pitch, etc.

Is there a resource that either explains this, or has spoken conversation that represents modern Greek tempo and pitch and can easily be slowed down?

Comment: What do you mean by "easily slowed down"?  Would a normal audio recording of conversation count (which can be slowed down or sped up with any reasonable audio editing software)?

Comment: @Flimzy: Mmm, I was imagining  "easily slowed down" by the ordinary standards of easiness on the web, including not requiring software or techniques that the average web user isn't aware of. I didn't exactly mean "easy for someone who knows how to capture audio content from the web and is also already proficient in using Audacity." And I was also imagining not having to struggle to hear slowed-down sound at the same pitch as it was recorded.